# Adding DialogFlow tags dynamically to a site by editing one common .JS file

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

This code is not working, how can I add dialogFlow tags to a whole site editing just this one .JS file, without adding tags manually to each page.

```
   var script = document.createElement("script");  // create a script DOM node
    script.src = "https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/messenger/bootstrap.js?v=1";  
    document.head.appendChild(script);  

   var div = document.createElement("div");
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
  div.outerHTML = "<df-messenger chat-title=\"Help\"   agent-id=\"id"   language-code=\"en\" ></df-messenger>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 //code here
});
```